# removing duplicate content python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, duplicates

I've got a text file containing multiple jobtitle. I want to remove the title that reoccurs. I created 2 empty array, one for all jobtitle and another which stores non-duplicate values.
The code i've used is:

```
with open('jobtitle.txt') as fp:
jobtitle =[]
jobtitle_original = []
for line in fp:
 jobtitle.append(line)
for i in range(0,len(jobtitle)):
 for j in range(0,len(jobtitle_original)):
  if jobtitle_original[j] == jobtitle[i]:
   continue
  else:
   jobtitle_original.append(jobtitle[i])
print jobtitle_original
```

But it returns me an empty array. I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: It's not surprising because `jobtitle_original` is 0 length in the beginning so the inner loop body is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `set`:

```
jobs = ['engineer','artist','mechanic','teacher','teacher','engineer','engineer']

print list(set(jobs))
['engineer','artist','mechanic','teacher']
```

A simpler demonstration:

```
>>> lst = [1,4,2,4,3,5,3,5,3,5,4,5,4]
>>> print list(set(lst))
[1,4,2,3,5]
```

`set` takes a list and creates a `set` of non-duplicate items. Then, you can simply cast it as a list using `list(set(something))`.

Comment: +1 for you. I've posted my own answer though, just to clarify how to deal with data coming from a file properly.

Answer (score 1):

Combining your file input and `set` solution.

```
with open('jobtitle.txt') as fp:
    result = set(fp.readlines())
```